# In a data.table remove identical consecutive values over certain times by group

Tags: r, data.table

In a `data.table`, if a certain column has identical values occurring consecutively over a certain number of times, I'd like to remove the corresponding rows. I also would like to do this by group.

For example, say `dt` is my `data.table`. I would like to remove rows if the same value occurs consecutively over 2 times in `Petal.Width` grouped by `Species`.

```
dt <- iris[c(1:3, 7:7, 51:53, 62:63), ]
setDT(dt)
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
# 3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
# 7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
# 51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
# 52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
# 53          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
# 62          5.9         3.0          4.2         1.5 versicolor
# 63          6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor
```

The desired outcome is a data.table with the following rows.

```
# 7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
# 51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
# 63          6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor
```

Comment: Something like this? `dt[, .SD[.N == 1], by = rleid(Species, Petal.Width)]`

Comment: @RonakShah is it ok if i use Species in the rleid in j as well?

Comment: @RonakShah quite close. I'd like to have the `Species` and `Petal.Width` in the outcome as well.

Comment: @chinsoon12 Sure. @ Suren I thought so, hence didn't put it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[dt[,{
    rl <- rleid(Species, Petal.Width)
    rw <- rowid(rl)
    .I[!rl %in% rl[rw > 1]]
}]]
```

output:

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1:          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
2:          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
3:          6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor
```

Comment: I was wondering which one to tick... This one does seem faster, but @Cole's one seemed more intuitive.

Comment: @Cole's answer is very elegant! `dt[, .SD[.N < 3], by = .(Petal.Width, Species)]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- iris[c(1:3, 7:7, 51:53, 62:63), ]
setDT(dt)

dt[dt[, .I[.N < 3], by = .(rleid(Petal.Width), Species)]$V1]
```

Thanks to @chinsoon12 for suggesting to wrap `rleid()` around `Pedal.Width` to filter out consecutive values.